# Protect SAM defined API with WAF

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, amazon-waf

How would one go about attaching a WAF to a SAM template defined API Gateway?
Is there a way to specigy the WAF's ARN in the template?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_WAFv2.html

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea but it would feel like you could use [custom domains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-edge-optimized-custom-domain-name.html) for this?

If you have a look on custom domains doc you could have your own domain pointing at your api, something like `api.my-domain.com/` which will create a Cloudfront distribution for your API.

Another thing you can explore if the Cloudfront domain you get does not allow the customisation you get [this article on how to fully customise your CF distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudfront-distribution/) at which point adding WAF on it shouldn't be a problem?